# Change code to autofit column width based on content of row

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code here which is working great but which I would like to fine-tune. Right now the macro copies three rows of values to a new workbook. These values are pasted without any format. Not all the content of the cells is visible because the column width is not large enough sometimes. My question is the following: how can i change the code provided below so as for the columns to become larger depending on the text in the first row pasted.
How do I autofit the columns depending on the content in the first row?

Code:

```
Public Sub pub_sub_ExportRows()

'#
'# declare private variables
'#
     Dim pvt_xls_Current As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim pvt_wbk_New As Excel.Workbook
     Dim pvt_lng_SelectedSourceRow As Long
     Dim pvt_flg_ValidRow As Boolean
     Dim pvt_lng_RowNumber As Long
     Dim pvt_lng_FirstColumn As Long
     Dim pvt_lng_LastColumn As Long
     Dim pvt_lng_ColumnNumber As Long
     Dim pvt_lng_TargetColumn As Long

'#
'# record the current row based on the active cell
'#
     Set pvt_xls_Current = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
     pvt_lng_SelectedSourceRow = ActiveCell.Row

'#
'# the maximum number of columns to be considered is not dependent on the columns        defined in the
'# worksheet, but rather by a limit imposed by the user - i.e. column HG is the last       column to be copied,
'# and column Q is the first column to be considered
'#
     pvt_lng_FirstColumn = Columns("Q").Column
     pvt_lng_LastColumn = Columns("HG").Column
     pvt_lng_TargetColumn = 0

'#
'# check if the selected row is valid by examining the values in the columns on that
'# row - any non-blank value implies that the selected row is valid - when looking at
'# the values the search starts in column Q as requested by the user
'#
     With pvt_xls_Current
          pvt_flg_ValidRow = False
          For pvt_lng_ColumnNumber = pvt_lng_FirstColumn To pvt_lng_LastColumn
               If LenB(.Cells(pvt_lng_SelectedSourceRow, pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Value) > 0 Then
                    pvt_flg_ValidRow = True
                    Exit For
               End If
          Next pvt_lng_ColumnNumber
     End With

     If Not pvt_flg_ValidRow Then
          MsgBox "You must select a valid - i.e. non empty - row"
          Exit Sub
     End If

     If pvt_lng_SelectSourceRow > 10000 Then
          MsgBox "You may not select a row > 10000"
          Exit Sub
     End If

'#
'# create a new workbook to hold the copied values and copy & paste the information to   the
'# newly created workbook
'#
     Set pvt_wbk_New = Application.Workbooks.Add
     With pvt_xls_Current
          For pvt_lng_ColumnNumber = pvt_lng_FirstColumn To pvt_lng_LastColumn

               If LenB(.Cells(pvt_lng_SelectedSourceRow, pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Value) > 0 And _
                    InStr(1, "$AF,$BF,$CG,$DH,$ES,$FV,$HD,$HF",    Split(Columns(pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Address, ":")(0)) = 0 Then
                         pvt_lng_TargetColumn = pvt_lng_TargetColumn + 1
                         pvt_wbk_New.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,    pvt_lng_TargetColumn).Value = .Cells(4, pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Value
                         pvt_wbk_New.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,   pvt_lng_TargetColumn).Value = .Cells(5, pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Value
                         pvt_wbk_New.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,  pvt_lng_TargetColumn).Value = .Cells(pvt_lng_SelectedSourceRow, pvt_lng_ColumnNumber).Value
               End If

          Next pvt_lng_ColumnNumber
     End With

'#
'# activate the new workbook
'#
     pvt_wbk_New.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: `columns to autofit depending on the content in the first row!` so you don't care if other rows in the column may not be fully visible?

Comment: Correct! I know that the content of the other rows will never be more than that of the first row!

Comment: Then just use the `.AutoFit` method on the column (as @DougGlancy has shown below).

Comment: +1 for well documented and laid out code: pretty rare in `VBA` !

Comment: I've had a few funnies when using `autofit` - mainly with expanding the column width to well beyond what is required. On the other hand it is a very powerful feature - in `SSRS` there is not equivalent which is a real draw-back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will autofit the entire row of the first cell being set to a value. It could obviously be simplified to just indicate row 1, but I tried to duplicate the code you used:

```
 pvt_wbk_New.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,pvt_lng_TargetColumn).EntireRow.Columns.Autofit
```