# How to autofit column width with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub RowHeightMin()
    Dim finalRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("A1:A" & finalRow).EntireRow.AutoFit
    
    For i = 2 To finalRow
        If Range("A" & i).EntireRow.RowHeight < 27 Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.RowHeight = 27
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have this as an example for a row autofit adjust, but just like for it's column counterpart.

Autofit would be based on it's row B cells.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this what you want? `Range("A1:A" & finalRow).EntireRow.RowHeight = 27` Actually I am not sure what your query is :)

Comment: I don't think excel has a "Row B", talk a look at the answer to [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124524/change-code-to-autofit-column-width-based-on-content-of-row)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example code, it will use `Rows(2)` to set the width of all columns.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).Columns.AutoFit
```

`#Edit`

Below is code to `AutoFit` the range for both rows and columns, and then resize rows if less the 27 to  27. `ThisWorkbook` is where your macro is saved. You need to change the worksheet name to yours sheet name if it is not "Sheet1". If you don't like using `SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` you can always define lastrow, lastcol variables.

```
Sub AutofitRange()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Define the workbook and worksheet
        
        'Assign the rng varaible using .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column)
    
        With rng
            .Rows.AutoFit 'Autofit the rows in the range
            .Rows(2).Columns.AutoFit 'AutoFit the columns in the range based on Row 2
            
            'Resize the rows in col 1 if less then 27
            If Columns(1).Rows.EntireRow.RowHeight < 27 Then Columns(1).Rows.RowHeight = 27
            .WrapText = False
        End With
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where could I put this at?

Comment: @KevinBIllings If I'm correct in that you want to set the width for all columns based on the data in Row(2), you need to replace  `Range("A1:A" & finalRow).EntireRow.AutoFit` with the code provide. To work correctly change  `Sheet1` to what ever sheet you are trying to set the column width. Additionally, you should always us a 'Worksheet object', not using it will default to the active worksheet, and can cause problems.

Comment: This gave me a subscript out of range

Comment: Thank you, I think the auto fit is working but it's word wrapping mid character, so House is like Hou-se, (next line)

Comment: @KevinBillings You have wrapping on, so since you wanted the column width set to the value length in Row 2; e.g. any value in the column F that is larger then the value in F2 will be wrapped. You need to turn off wrapping. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose OP wants to autofit all columns, could be changed easily though.

```
Sub ColWidthMin()
Const MinimalWidth As Double = 12.56
With Sheet1                    ' using the sheet's Code(Name)
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
    'autofit columns
    rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If rng.Columns(i).ColumnWidth < MinimalWidth Then
            rng.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = MinimalWidth
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```